# Calculations between aggregates in power pivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm looking for a way to quickly calculate differences between aggregates using power pivot for excel (2013).

I have a tabular dataset that I'm creating pivot tables from; this dataset has one measure and multiple attributes. What I'd like to do is show the differences between the SUM(Value) by 'Attribute' Value 'A' vs 'Attribute' Value 'B'.

Here is an example of my data (the '?' values are what I want to calculate):

```
╔═══════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ Color ║ AvgOfMeasure ║ MaxOfMeasure ║ MinOfMeasure ║ Spread(Min vs Max) ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ Blue  ║ 50           ║ 75           ║ 25           ║ ?                  ║
║ Red   ║ 100          ║ 150          ║ 50           ║ ?                  ║
║ Delta ║ ?            ║ ?            ║ ?            ║ ?                  ║
╚═══════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

I'm new to power pivot but I am very familiar with T-SQL and have written some basic MDX (although it's been a while...). The way I've done this so far is to just manually copy the data out (its not a large set when summarized) and add my difference calculations after the fact. I'm inclined to think that there is a better way to do this though...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thus far I haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: For the "Spread" you could use a calculated field.  In your Pivot Options up top (with the Pivot Table selected), click formulas > Calculated Field.  You'll then use this to setup Max - Min.

Comment: Thanks TMH8885 - I haven't looked at this yet but hopefully this afternoon. Do you think the same approach will work for the other aggregate calculations? Hopefully I explained what I was looking for with enough detail - if not let me know.

Comment: I don't believe it will work for your "Delta" row, just for the "Spread" column.

Comment: How do you want to calculate delta?

Comment: Delta is the difference between aggregates. For example, the delta between MaxOfMeasure for Blue and Red would be 75. I have an idea about how to do this using native pivot table functionality that I'm going to try later today. I'm hoping I could simply drop in my aggregate twice and display the 2nd 'version' as a column difference.

Comment: Just an update, I was able to figure this out using native pivot table functionality. What I did was pull in the 'Measure' field again and change the Value Field settings. In that menu, you can show a value as a calculation; one of the options is to calculate a difference based on an attribute (in my case, color). It doesn't look exactly what I envisioned above... but it's functional and will work. I'd mark this as answered but I don't think I have sufficient rep yet :/